# How to use AJAX action in my controller method?

Tags: magento2

I'm integrating the payment module, I want to call ajax to the controller for third party API. 
Does anyone know how to do it? Thanks in advance.

I've got a getAjax.php controller at
 `vendorName\moduleName\Controller\Index`

I want to use `getPrice()` method with ajax.

Here is   `GetAjax.php`

```
<?php

namespace vendorName\moduleName\Controller\Index;

use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context;

class GetAjax extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action {

        public function __construct(
               Context  $context,
               \Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\JsonFactory $resultJsonFactory
        ) {

            $this->resultJsonFactory = $resultJsonFactory;
            parent::__construct($context);
        }

    public function getPrice(){


            print "heuss" ;
    }

        public function execute() {
        /** @var \Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\Json $result */
        $result = $this->resultJsonFactory->create();
        return $result->setData(['success' => true]);
       } 
}
```

And this is the AJAX.js file

```
define(['jquery'],
    function ($) {
         $(document).ready(function() {


              $.ajax({

                url : 'Iostpaymagento/index/getAjax',
                type : 'GET',
                data: {
                    format: 'JSON.stringify'
                },
                dataType:'json',
                success : function(data) {              
                    alert('Data: '+data);
                },
                error : function(request,error)
                {
                    alert("Error");
                }
            });

         });
    });
```

I am getting error like

```
require.js:166 Uncaught Error: Mismatched anonymous define() module: function ($) {
```

Answer (score 1):

Magento 2 does not allow you to do that.

If you want to use that getPrice method I recommend you to [create an API](https://inchoo.net/magento-2/magento-2-custom-api/) for that